# Regular Expression for renaming Files

Tags: regex, powershell

i need a regular expression for renaming hundreds of pdf files with the **PowerRename** tool of the Microsoft PowerToys toolbox or alternatively with Windows PowerShell. The files are named like this:

```
100_20_Mustermann_Max_something_else.pdf
5421_826_Mustermann_Sam_something_else.pdf
```

I want to replace the third underline "_" with a comma plus space ", "
The result should be:

```
100_20_Mustermann, Max_something_else.pdf
5421_826_Mustermann, Sam_something_else.pdf
```

I am not familiar with regEx
can someone help?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann The first line of the question says he's using the PowerRename tool or PowerShell.

Comment: `^([^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+)_` matches everything up to the third `_`, and puts everything before that underscore in a capture group that can be copied into the replacement.

Comment: thanks so far, but what ist the expression for replacement?

Comment: I don't know PowerRename or PowerShell, so I don't know their syntax for this. The replacement should be capture group 1  followed by comma and space. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: The result now is like this:
Max_something_else.pdf
Sam_something_else.pdf

Comment: Looks like you left out the comma in the replacement string.

Comment: `gci *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?<=^([^_]*_){2}[^_]*)_',', ' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gci | % {
    $newName = $_.FullName -replace '([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(.+)', '$1_$2_$3, $4_$5_$6'

    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName $newName -WhatIf
}
```

This Powershell should work for you given that all the files in the directory the script is run, match the file name examples provided.

It's just a straightforward capture of the 6 groups around the 5 underscores and then just rebuilt with the third underscore substitution.

You can remove the **-WhatIf** safety catch once you are happy to go ahead and rename the files for real.